# Zenject. Как получить привязки из дочернего GameObjectContext?

Tags: c#, unity3d, zenject

Такая иерархия объектов на сцене:

[image: Scene]

- На объектах Picture и на всех Star находится GameObjectContext.
- На Picture находится PictureInstaller
- На Star находится StarInstaller

Оба представляют собой MVP сущности, т.е. в инсталлерах происходит связывание Model, View и Presenter.

Как мне в PictureModel получить все StarModel'и?

PictureInstaller:

[image: PictureInstaller]

StarInstaller:

[image: StarInstaller]

Comment: В PictureModel есть метод Initialize(IEnumerable<StarModel> stars) с [Inject]. Но stars всегда пустая.